# Access unique query update from one table to another

Tags: ms-access

Good morning.  I deleted my previous post since it was confusing to all.  I am going to present it a different way.  I am trying to update field values from table "current" into table "all holds" using "SHPMT ID" as seen in this photo:  I need to place the "FILERENTRTYNBR" numbers into the correct field.

[Update Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARI8R.png)

The next photo is the "SHPMT ID" numbers and "FILERENTRYNBR" numbers I am trying to update into table "all holds":

[The data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkSnI.png)

As you can see, the last "SHPMT ID" numbers are the same that are assigned to three different set of "FILERENTRYNBR" numbers.  When I run the query, the single "SHPMT ID" numbers have no problem assigning the correct "FILERENTRNBR" into table "all holds", but once it runs into the "222222" (SHPMT ID), access only assigns one FILERENTRYNBR number for all three.  My question would be is there a special expression for this unique update query?  If there is way to assign each separate "FILERENTRNBR" number to each set of similar "SHPMT ID" number, I would appreciate it greatly.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Still confusing. Should provide sample raw data and desired output as text tables, not images. Why do those tables not show any primary keys?

Comment: The primary key is SHPMT ID

Comment: You may be using it as a PK but it appears not to have been designated so in the table design. Strongly advise not to use spaces in naming convention. All upper case is also poor practice - it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring what looks like table normalization problems.  You can probably build an AllHolds2 table from the Current and AllHolds table.  Then after verifying everything is correct replace AllHolds with AllHolds2.  In the query hook Current and AllHolds on Shpmt.  Then find the right summary function(probably first for all of them) for all the variables in AllHolds you want to generalize across FilerEntryNBR.
[image]

```
current:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    FileEntryNBR    |      ShpmtID       |    CargoDescription     |           ShipmentQuantity           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR01               |             111111 | e                       |                                    1 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR01               |             162897 | d                       |                                    1 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR02               |             162898 | b                       |                                    2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR03               |             162898 | C                       |                                    2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR01               |             162899 | a                       |                                    1 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR02               |             222222 | f                       |                                    3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR03               |             222222 | g                       |                                    3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DR04               |             222222 | h                       |                                    3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

all holds:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID         |     CargoDescription     |       Shpmt        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | a                        |             162899 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | b                        |             162898 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | c                        |             162898 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | d                        |             162897 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 | e                        |             111111 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  6 | f                        |             222222 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  7 | g                        |             222222 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  8 | h                        |             222222 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
AllHolds2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          ShpmtID           |    FileEntryNBR    |  CargoDescripion   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     111111 | DR01               | e                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     162897 | DR01               | d                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     162898 | DR02               | b                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     162898 | DR03               | b                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     162899 | DR01               | a                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     222222 | DR02               | f                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     222222 | DR03               | f                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     222222 | DR04               | f                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note: Group By is used for Shpmt and FileEntryNBR.
Note: to get the totals row (google totals query access) right click for the context menu and select totals.