# Access update query problem from one table to another table

Tags: ms-access

Good morning to all.  This will be my third attempt to make this simple as possible.  I appreciate for all who have tried to help me.  I really am.  I am very new to Access.  Here it goes.  I have an access database that downloads from an excel file with data.  It creates a "current" (source) table before it downloads the data into "all holds" (destination) table. Certain fields such as "FILERENTRYNBR" are empty in "all holds" table where the next download will update that field from my "current" (source) table if there is any.  This is how the data looks in "current" table after creating the table after a download.  This is just an example.  I brought the numbers down for simplicity.  It's usually in the hundreds.

Current Table (source)
[Current Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hApU0.jpg)

My destination table looks like this before the update.

All Holds Table (destination)
[All Holds Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR8q0.jpg)

I have created an update query using the SHPMT ID as the inner join from both tables, but there is a problem trying to update with similar SHPMT ID's (222222).  It only works with identical matching SHPMT ID's.  When the update query runs into similar SHPMT ID's, it assigns only one "FILERENTRYNBR" into the "all holds" table as follows:

All Holds Table (destination) with similar FILERENTRYNBR's
[All Holds Table Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPjVl.jpg)

Notice the three "2720-3335498-DR04" numbers assign to each SHPMT ID's (222222).  I am looking for:

All Holds Table (destination) with correct FILERENTRNBR's
[All Holds Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPzlC.jpg)

Notice how each FILERENTRYNBR (2720-3335498-DR02, 2720-3335498-DR03, and 2720-3335498-DR04) is different for each similar SHPMT ID (222222).  I put the "PORT ARVL CD" field along with it because it is unique to only that "FILERENTRYNBR" field, where it can be used to update that appropriate SHPMT ID field if it can be of help.  The update query I am using has no problem updating FILERENTRYNBR's with single identical SHPMT ID's but runs into a problem when trying to update non-identical FILERENTRYNBR's with similar SHPMT ID's.  Thanks for your time and hope this helps.

Comment: Since `FILERENTRYNBR` is not unique are you able to inner join on `PORT ARVL CD` as well?

Comment: Yes.  I tried.  Just won't update from that point on.  Leaves the "all holds" table with blank values.  Like it does not know what to do with three separate FILERENTRYNBR's to three similar SHPMT ID's.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit in the query?

Comment: Yes.  I can edit in the query.  I tried many different inner joins.  Nothing.  Maybe a SQL might help but have no idea to go about it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a SQL might help' - you are trying SQL, that's what the update query is. Yes, you already posed this question and received an answer which you did not respond to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982871/access-unique-query-update-from-one-table-to-another. Also did not accommodate request to present data as text tables, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Both ShpmtID and PortArvlCd are needed to uniquely identify a FileEntryNBR.  Please notice that now every value of FileEntryNBR in Holds is in the same table as the corresponding value from current after going back and sorting on Port:

[image]
Query10 edited to be sorted on port:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    ShpmtID     |       Holds.FileEntryNBR       |       PortArvlCd        |          Current.FileEntryNBR          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         162897 | DR02                           | A                       | DR02                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         162898 | DR03                           | B                       | DR03                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         162897 | DR01                           | C                       | 1                                      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         111111 | DR01                           | D                       | DR01                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         222222 |                                | E                       | DR02                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         222222 |                                | F                       | DR03                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         222222 |                                | G                       | DR04                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL: SELECT Holds.ShpmtID, Holds.FileEntryNBR, Holds.PortArvlCd, Current.FileEntryNBR
FROM [Current] INNER JOIN Holds ON (Current.ShpmtID = Holds.ShpmtID) AND (Current.PortArvlCd = Holds.PortArvlCd)
ORDER BY Holds.PortArvlCd;
```

Current:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      ShpmtID       |    FileEntryNBR    |       PortArvlCd        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162897 | DR02               | A                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162898 | DR03               | B                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162897 | 1                  | C                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             111111 | DR01               | D                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 | DR02               | E                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 | DR03               | F                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 | DR04               | G                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Holds:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      ShpmtID       |    FileEntryNBR    |       PortArvlCd        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162897 | DR02               | A                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162898 | DR03               | B                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162897 | DR01               | C                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             111111 | DR01               | D                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 |                    | E                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 |                    | F                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 |                    | G                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now change the select query to an update there is no need to show the extra variables:

[image]

```
to overwrite rather than insert remove the is null criteria.
sql: 
UPDATE [Current] INNER JOIN Holds ON (Current.PortArvlCd = Holds.PortArvlCd) AND (Current.ShpmtID = Holds.ShpmtID) SET Holds.FileEntryNBR = [Current].[FileEntryNBR]
WHERE (((Holds.FileEntryNBR) Is Null));
```

Holds after update:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      ShpmtID       |    FileEntryNBR    |       PortArvlCd        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162897 | DR02               | A                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162898 | DR03               | B                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             162897 | DR01               | C                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             111111 | DR01               | D                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 | DR02               | E                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 | DR03               | F                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|             222222 | DR04               | G                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for the tip.  I did exactly what you wanted me to do.  Both ShpmtID and PortArvlCd are needed, BUT, unfortunately PortArvleCD is not unique or have the same fields in both Current (source) and All Holds (Destination) tables.  It's in the source table but not in the destination table.  My mistake.  It works fine if both fields (PortArvlCD) had the same data.  I guess it's impossible to update anything with only the similar SHPMT ID's (222222) with separate Filerentrynbr's, and so one by itself.  Thanks for he help.

Comment: in that case I would move from sql to vba.  you probably need to ask another question with a more relevant minimal reproducible example